# Sum of Harmonic Series

Tags: number-theory, induction

While going through the exercises I found this problem on Induction:

> Let
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i} = \frac{p}{q}.$$
>   Prove that $p$ is odd and $q$ is even $\forall\ n\in\Bbb{N}$ and  $n \gt 1$.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: But it's not true for $n =1$.

Comment: Oops!Sorry it would be for n greater than 1

Comment: Also I guess you mean $\gcd(p,q)=1$ since otherwise you can always multiply by $\frac{2}{2}$.

Comment: You need to add that p and q are relatively prime for your proposition to be true

Comment: @user211217 if u want i can post a solution without induction

Comment: @IULA Yeah any solution are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

By induction, it works well :

Suppose that $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} = \frac{p}{q}$ with $gcp(p,q) = 1$ and q is even

Then $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k} = \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{p}{q} = \frac{q+(n+1)p}{q(n+1)}$

Now let's write $q = 2^u\tilde{q}$ and $n+1 = 2^v \tilde{k}$, with $\tilde{q}$ and $\tilde{k}$ odd

Then the fraction become $\frac{2^u\tilde{q}+2^v \tilde{k}p}{2^u\tilde{q}2^v \tilde{k}}$

If $u \leq v$, you have $\frac{\tilde{q}+2^{v-u} \tilde{k}p}{2^v\tilde{q}\tilde{k}}$ (same idea if $v \leq u$)

And here is your proof that the numerator is odd and the denominator even.

You need then to simplify the expression to continue the induction (= get a p' and q' relatively prime with $\frac{p'}{q'}=\frac{q+(n+1)p}{q(n+1)}$)

Comment: Your second step is false if n+1 is even

Comment: Oh, yes, there is more work to do. You need to suppose that $q = 2^uv$ and $n+1=2^wk$, with v an k odd. Then the power of two can be simplified, and you can continue

Comment: if u = w that does not work out. Powers are added.  but you have multiplied them in the denominator

Comment: No, it's right. If u=w, at the numerator you have $2^u(v+kp)$ and at the denominator $2^{u+w}vk=2^{2u}vk$ (with the notation of the comment). If you divide both by $2^u$, you get $\frac{v+kp}{2^uvk}$

Comment: but then q + kp may be even, WRT the comments which is v + kp since q(or v) is odd and so is kp. and we don't know how many powers of two their sum contains.

Comment: Yes, you are right, need to think a little about that. Maybe we can show by induction that u > w.